# Counting problem, discrete mathematics

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let A={1,2,3,4} and B={5,6,7,8,9,10,11}.
How many injective functions are there from B into A?

Now, I'm pretty sure the answer is 0, because based on my calculations, wouldn't you do 4!/(4-7)!, which would give you 0, which means there are no injective functions?

to clarify, injective also means one to one

Comment: For a function to be injective, *each* element in the domain must be mapped to a *unique* element in the codomain. $B$ has seven elements and $A$ has four, so there is no such function.

Comment: The only interesting question is what occurs if you interchange the roles of $A$ and $B$ in the question.  Can you do that?  If so, then that skill, plus Rick's comment above, is all you really need to know.

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion is correct, but the reasoning is very strange, and probably incorrect.

You can't have an injective function from $B$ into $A$ because there are more elements of $B$ than there are of $A$.  So it's impossible that each element of $B$ is assigned a different element of $A$, which is what an injective function is required to do. You simply can't serve four desserts to seven guests while giving each guest a different dessert, so the  number of ways to do it is zero.

To cite the calculation of $\frac{4!}{(4-7)!} = 0$ is not correct, because $(4-7)!$ is either undefined or zero, depending on how you want to see it, and either way $\frac{4!}{(4-7)!}$ is not meaningful. The $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ formula only makes sense when $n-m \ge 0$. I don't know where you got this formula from but it should have had some qualification attached that said that the formula only applies when $n\ge m$ and that when $n\lt m$ there are no injective functions.